# {exp:channel:form} class param not working

Tags: 2.7.0, channel-form

I have this code

```
{exp:channel:form
  channel="foo"
  class="form-horizontal"
                ....
}
```

But I don’t see the class “form-horizontal” on my form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been accepted as a bug by Ellislabs

https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19707